# The question about finding a basis for a linear subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say there's a subspace
$$
U = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \mid x_1 = 2x_2 \}. 
$$
It is a linear subspace over $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then how can I find the basis for this subspace?

My idea is to firstly find a list of vectors in $U$ such as $(v_1,v_2, \dots)$ and make sure that they can span $U$, then I start to check the redundancy of this list (linear independence). If the list is not redundant anymore (this list is linearly independent), then it is the basis for $U$.

My question is, how can I find a list of vectors in $U$ that can span $U$ (find a spanning list for $U$), or my idea might be wrong, could somebody help me and give some ideas?

Comment: The vectors in $U$ have the form $(2x_2,x_2,x_3) = x_2\cdot (2,1,0) + x_3\cdot (0,0,1)$. Can you now guess a basis for $U$? BTW, **the** basis doesn't exist. There are always infinitely many bases.

Comment: Therefore, actually, this subspace is a two-dimensional subspace, and vectors like (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) can be the basis of this subspace？

Comment: Nope. It's two-dimensional, yes. But your suggested basis is false. These vectors are not even contained in $U$. You can read off a basis from my previous comment.

Comment: Oh yes, it seems that $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be any number in the field, so list ( $ x_2 * (2,1,0) $  , $ x_3 * (0,0,1) $ ) are just basis? and $ x_2 $ can be any number in R, so as $ x_3 $. Therefore, $ ( (2,1,0),(0,0,1) ) $ is a basis, so does $ ( (4,2,0),(0,0,3) ) $. Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct, Hubert. Very good!

Comment: Thank you. I just learned linear algebra, some definitions and questions are really confusing. Thank you for explaining this to a novice like me.